# Python Pandas -- mapping the values in two data frames

Tags: python, pandas, merge, mapping, vectorization

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`.

I am trying to figure out the best way to perform a mapping that for each row in `df1`, I would like to search for a match (`id`, `time_by_hour`) in `df2` and then fill the corresponding value in `df2` back into `df1`.

Below is the `df1_final` as I would like it to look finally.

Thank you in advance!

```
df1
Out[100]: 
  id             time_by_min        time_by_hour  value
0  a 2017-06-30 01:25:00.000 2017-06-30 02:00:00    NaN
1  a 2017-06-30 01:36:32.308 2017-06-30 02:00:00    NaN
2  a 2017-06-30 02:25:00.000 2017-06-30 03:00:00    NaN
3  a 2017-06-30 02:36:32.308 2017-06-30 03:00:00    NaN
4  b 2017-06-30 01:25:00.000 2017-06-30 02:00:00    NaN
5  b 2017-06-30 01:36:32.308 2017-06-30 02:00:00    NaN
6  b 2017-06-30 02:25:00.000 2017-06-30 03:00:00    NaN

df2
Out[101]: 
  id        time_by_hour  value
0  a 2017-06-30 02:00:00    100
1  a 2017-06-30 03:00:00    200
2  b 2017-06-30 02:00:00    150
3  b 2017-06-30 03:00:00     30
4  c 2017-06-30 02:00:00     80
5  c 2017-06-30 03:00:00    900

df1_final
Out[102]: 
  id             time_by_min        time_by_hour  value
0  a 2017-06-30 01:25:00.000 2017-06-30 02:00:00    100
1  a 2017-06-30 01:36:32.308 2017-06-30 02:00:00    100
2  a 2017-06-30 02:25:00.000 2017-06-30 03:00:00    200
3  a 2017-06-30 02:36:32.308 2017-06-30 03:00:00    200
4  b 2017-06-30 01:25:00.000 2017-06-30 02:00:00    150
5  b 2017-06-30 01:36:32.308 2017-06-30 02:00:00    150
6  b 2017-06-30 02:25:00.000 2017-06-30 03:00:00     30
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can look at `merge`

```
df1['value']=df1[['time_by_hour','id']].merge(df2,how='left').value
```

Comment: @Sam yw~ :-) , if this is what you need, can you consider accept it ? check mark at the left